# How to get the textbox's id by cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple textboxes inside a div element. I want to insert some text one of the textbox by cursor position on a button click. I am successfully inserted text if I know the id of a textbox, but i am having problem to know the element wheres the cursor currently positioned.

```
<div>

    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
    <input type="text" id="Text2" />
    <input type="text" id="Text3" />
    <input type="button" value="Add" id="btnAdd" />
    </div>

$('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            insertDataVarables(document.getElementById('txt1'), 'insertedText')
    });

    function insertDataVarables(myField, myValue) {
        //IE support
        if (document.selection) {
            myField.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text = myValue;
        }
        //MOZILLA and others
        else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
            var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
            var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
            myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos)
                + myValue
                + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
            myField.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
            myField.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
        } else {
            myField.value += myValue;
        }
    }
```

So how could I know the textbox id by cursor position.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is somewhat unclear, if you  click a textbox it's focused, and the click event handler fires on that textbox, setting it as `this` inside the event handler, so why would you need the ID of an element at a specific location? Anyway, there's always `document.elementFromPoint()` to get an element at a specific location.

Comment: I want to insert some text on button click not on textbox's  events

Comment: So you want to insert text in the currently **focused** input, when clicking a button ?

Comment: @adeneo yes. But problem is I have multiple textboxes and all are generated dynamically.

Comment: It's a lot easier than you think, just use the `mousedown` event and the `activeElement` to get the focused input, like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/yu92gj37/

Comment: @adeneo. Its working. Thanks a lot. You can put an answer so other will also gets help for you answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch the focused input when clicking a button, you have to listen to the `mousedown` event as it fires before the input loses focus.
The `click` event is too late, the input has already lost focused by that time.

To get the currently focused (active) element, one can use `document.activeElement`.

So something like this :

```
$('#btnAdd').on('mousedown', function() {
  var el = document.activeElement;

    insertDataVarables(el, 'insertedText')
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yu92gj37/1/)

Answer (score 0):

When a cursor is positioned in a textbox save it in a global variable. The on button click insert the value to the saved element. Hope following code snippet will help you.

```js
var selctedElm;

$(document).on('click', '#btnAdd', function () {
    selctedElm && selctedElm.val('insertedText');
});

$(document).on('click', 'input[type=text]', function() {
    selctedElm = $(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
    <input type="text" id="Text2" />
    <input type="text" id="Text3" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Add" id="btnAdd" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer given by **adeneo**

```
$('#btnAdd').on('mousedown', function() {
      var el = document.activeElement;

        insertDataVarables(el, 'insertedText')
    });

        function insertDataVarables(myField, myValue) {
            //IE support
            if (document.selection) {
                myField.focus();
                sel = document.selection.createRange();
                sel.text = myValue;
            }
            //MOZILLA and others
            else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
                var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
                var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
                myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos)
                    + myValue
                    + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
                myField.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
                myField.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
            } else {
                myField.value += myValue;
            }
        }

    <div>

        <input type="text" id="txt1" />
        <input type="text" id="Text2" />
        <input type="text" id="Text3" />
        <input type="button" value="Add" id="btnAdd" />
        </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to leave, and when I came back I forgot to update the page, and just saw your comment, so I posted an answer before seeing the other answers that had been posted in the meantime. Anyway, it's there now, good luck !